# Is jsFiddle completely accurate?

Tags: html, css, jsfiddle

If I make a mockup in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and then deploy that Javascript to my website, will the webpage look exactly the same as the "result" panel from jsFiddle?

Comment: As far as I know, Yes. Because JSFiddle renders all your content in an IFrame

Comment: Note that there is a "normalize CSS" option on jsfiddle (checked by default) which *will* affect how the content is rendered.

Answer (score 12):

jsFiddle is best for testing JavaScript code, not for designing entire websites. If you're looking to test JavaScript code that you want to run on your site, then yes, it will execute JavaScript as any other site would as the code ultimately is running in your browser.

Answer (score 2):

We are trying to not pollute the result with any unnecessary JS or CSS code. You can check that with rendering an empty fiddle.

The latest MooTools and onLoad "code wrap" is selected by default. Change the code wrap to one of the "no wrap" options and it'll disappear.

As it was said before, result is rendered inside an iframe. If you're a registered user you can always display it (the latest [Run]) using http://jsfiddle.net/draft/. Please do read about it in http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#draft. It's extremely useful if you wish to edit a fiddle in your favorite browser and test in another.

Answer (score 0):

The way your page looks doesn't depend on jsfiddle or other cool js engines... It depends on the browser you are using to look at it, so... yes, your page will look exactly the same in si in the "result" box...

Just to be clear, jsfiddle is a set of frames. Every frame has its own `<html>`, `<head>`, `<body>` tags, so it is a REAL page. there is no trick on it.

Comment: Set of frames? Just one frame - the Results.

Comment: Look at the code, there is an iframe for every box. Study harder next time instead of downvoting without any real motivation.

Comment: I'm the co-creator of JsFiddle, there's only one iframe - obviously I'm not even counting the ones generated by CodeMirror.